# TextFields not updating/repainting correctly on codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a problem with `TextFields` not updating correctly when they gain focus using the virtual keyboard in Codenameone apps on Android devices.

I gave the `TextField` a value (value '0') and added multiples underneath each other. I then pressed on a `TextField`, where it gains focus, and I type something in. Once the value is entered, I press 'Next' on the virtual keyboard, and the value in the next `TextField` (the '0') gets bolded (there's 2 '0' values on top of one another). When I then press back, to clear the '0', one of them disappear, and when I try type, the text if written over the '0' value.

This seems to happen when the next `TextField` is off-screen, and it seems to not update correctly. When I erase one '0', and lose focus on the TextFields, the other '0' also disappears, implying its not refreshing correctly.
The same happens with text hints.

The test app I used:

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    hi.addComponent(new Label("Hi World"));
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.addComponent(getEntry());
    hi.show();
}

public Container getEntry() {
    Container c = new Container();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Label lbl = new Label("Testing..");

    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.setConstraint(TextField.DECIMAL);
    tf.setText("0");
    c.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, lbl);
    c.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, tf);
    return c;

}
```

**SCREENSHOTS**

In the first image, you can see the text being bolded, which is actually 2 '0' values on top of one another.

[image: the text being bolded]

The second image is what it looks like after you pressed the back button on the virtual keyboard to erase the '0'.

[image]

The third image shows what happens if you continue to try type something in,

[image]

and lastly, the fourth image shows how the TextField looks like after it loses focus (pressed on another TextField).

[image]

**FURTHER DETAILS**

This was replicated on Android devices, using versions 4.2.2, and 4.4.2.
This is far easier to reproduce on smaller screens; I believe this is due ot the nature of the bug where the `TextField` is off-screen.

Comment: Hi,
This remains unanswered.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Ever solved this? I'm having a similar problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the layout of your Form to

```
setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
setScrollableY(true);
```

Comment: Hi,
In the actual app (not the test one) where this occurs, it does use a BoxLayout (Y-AXIS) and has scrollable true. Unfortunately it still has the same behaviour.