# CodeNameOne - Library update broke textboxes

Tags: android, textfield, codenameone

I think it was two updates before the present one that TextField were working. Now when selecting a TextField which has text inside the text moves to the side AND remains as a ghost in the middle of the TextField. New and old texts overlap.
Any idea what changed with respect to TextField? Or better can I revert to a library version of my choosing?

This only seems to happen in Android devices, IOS (and simulator) works fine.

Found this question which seems to be the same (only with the text uncentered), but it has no accepted answer (tried the answer there to no avail):
[TextFields not updating/repainting correctly on codenameone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329346/textfields-not-updating-repainting-correctly-on-codenameone)

[image: Example of the broken text field]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simulator only issue that doesn't affect the device. If so it should be addressed by [this commit](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/4265c53e5bafafa169811540866927bf1e6483df).

Since updates occur every Friday this should be fixed on June 3rd 2016.